# Adding more barcodes to a 4x6 label in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am trying to make a 4x6 label with 7 code-39 barcodes on it, but it seems like my VBA code is overwriting each barcode. The data is pulled from an excel file in cells B2 - B8, right now I am stuck on just getting 2 to print. It just prints the data from B3 instead of B2 and B3 at this time.

I'd also like to figure out how to get text to show up above each barcode from columns A2 - A8, but haven't even gotten to this step yet. I've tried looking up how to do this but haven't found much information on VBA to word apps. Below is my code, I would really appreciate any help as I don't have any experience with VBA.

```
Sub Button2_Click()
Dim WdApp As Object, WdDoc As Object, StrCd As String, StrCl As String
With ActiveSheet
  StrCd = Chr(34) & .Range("B2").Value & Chr(34)
  StrCl = Chr(34) & .Range("B3").Value & Chr(34)
  
End With
Set WdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application"): Set WdDoc = WdApp.Documents.Add
With WdDoc
  .PageSetup.PageWidth = 288: .PageSetup.PageHeight = 432: .PageSetup.RightMargin = 36: .PageSetup.LeftMargin = 36
  .Fields.Add .Range, -1, "DISPLAYBARCODE " & StrCd & " CODE39 \d \t", False
  .Fields.Add .Range, -1, "DISPLAYBARCODE " & StrCl & " CODE39 \d \t", False
  With .Range
    With .ParagraphFormat
      .LineSpacingRule = 0 'wdLineSpaceSingle
      .SpaceBefore = 0
      .SpaceAfter = 1
    End With
    
    .Copy
  End With
  ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="Picture (Enhanced Metafile)", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
  .Close False
End With
Set WdDoc = Nothing: WdApp.Quit: Set WdApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

[image]

[image: Ideal final product]

Comment: As previously requested - please post a screenshot of what the final product of your code should look like - it's difficult to guess exactly what you're going for here...

Comment: I added a screenshot of what I currently have now. I would like additional barcodes to show up in the 4x6 label. Right now only the one barcode shows up and the B3 spot shows up over the B2 one. Does this help?

Comment: The bottom picture is what I am ideally going for, just 7-8 barcodes with a brief description below each one on a 4x6 label. The user would just fill in B2-B8, hit the button and it would print this label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Button2_Click()
    Const PER_ROW As Long = 3 '# of labels per row in layout
    Dim WdApp As Object, WdDoc As Object, StrCd As String, StrCl As String
    Dim c As Range, wsData As Worksheet, wsLabel As Worksheet, v, i As Long
    
    'set up a Word doc for generating the barcodes
    Set WdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    WdApp.Visible = True
    Set WdDoc = WdApp.Documents.Add
    With WdDoc.PageSetup
        .PageWidth = 288
        .PageHeight = 432
        .RightMargin = 36
        .LeftMargin = 36
    End With
    
    Set wsData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Label Data") 'data for labels on this sheet
    Set wsLabel = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Label")     'labels created on this sheet
    
    For Each c In wsData.Range("B2:B9").Cells
        v = Trim(c.Value)
        If Len(v) > 0 Then
            i = i + 1
            With WdDoc.Fields.Add(WdDoc.Range, -1, "DISPLAYBARCODE " & v & _
                                   " CODE39 \d \t", False)
                .Copy
                If Not PasteWithRetry(wsLabel) Then 'make sure the paste succeeds
                    MsgBox "Paste failed!"
                    Exit For
                End If
                .Delete
            End With
            With wsLabel.Shapes(wsLabel.Shapes.Count) 'get the pasted shape
                .Top = Fix((i - 1) / PER_ROW) * 100    '...and position it
                .Left = ((i - 1) Mod PER_ROW) * 220
            End With
        End If
   Next c
    
   WdDoc.Close False
   WdApp.Quit
End Sub

'Pasting pictures in a loop is often unreliable, so
'  this tries multiple times before giving up...
'Returns True if paste was successful
Function PasteWithRetry(ws As Worksheet) As Boolean
    Dim n As Long, pasted As Boolean
    For n = 1 To 10               'try 10 times to paste
        On Error Resume Next      'ignore any paste error
        ws.PasteSpecial Format:="Picture (Enhanced Metafile)", _
                                Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
        pasted = (Err.Number = 0) 'no error = pasted OK
        On Error GoTo 0           'stop ignoring errors
        If pasted Then
            PasteWithRetry = True
            Exit Function   'exit if pasted OK
        End If
        DoEvents
    Next n
End Function
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: This makes sense to me, but I am getting an error on the line "With wsLabel.Shapes(wsLabel.Shapes.Count)" down in the button function. The error is "the index into the specified collection is out of bounds" One other thing that might be worth mentioning is that the label isn't printing on the Label worksheet, it is printing on the Label Data sheet instead. I'll keep trying to debug, I appreciate the help!

Comment: You can ignore that last comment, I fixed that, my only problem now is that it is printing on a separate doc for each barcode, whereas I need it all on the same doc/label. Either way I am much farther now so I appreciate it

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "printing on a separate doc for each barcode" ?

Comment: When I click on the barcodes that get pasted I was hoping they would all be on the same image/doc, I just called it a document since it is sized on a word document. The idea is to have all 8 of these printed onto the same word doc/image to easily make a label

Comment: OK I totally misunderstood that - your code copy-pastes back to Excel so I assumed you were creating the printout there and the Word doc was only being used to create the barcode images.

Comment: ...but there's no reason you can't lay the barcodes out in Excel if you set the sheet's page layout appropriately.  If there are other pieces of information you need to overlay/position along with each barcode then you could do that using additional shapes with text.

Comment: I will play around with that and see what I can come up with, I really appreciate it as this is my first time ever touching VBA and I am not good with excel either