# Error when pasting chart image to worksheet: "Method 'Paste' of object '_Worksheet' failed", error will clear with single continue

Tags: excel, vba

I paste a chart image from another worksheet.

I get this error occasionally:

> Method 'Paste' of object '_Worksheet' failed

The code that triggers it.

```vb
Dim ViewerWS As Worksheet, myWS As Worksheet
Set ViewerWS = Sheets("Viewer")
Dim InCopy As Long, InPaste As Long
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
Dim count As Long
For Each myWS In Sheets
    If Mid(myWS.Name, 1, 1) = "6" And Len(myWS.Name) = 10 Then
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    ' Erreur "Method 'Paste' of object '_Worksheet' failed"
GoInCopy:
            On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
            InCopy = InCopy + 1
            DoEvents
            myWS.ChartObjects("main").CopyPicture
            InCopy = 0
            
GoInPaste:
            On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
            InPaste = InPaste + 1
            DoEvents
            ViewerWS.Paste
            InPaste = 0
Next
Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
    Debug.Print "Error caught : " & Err.Description & " / " & InCopy & " / " & InPaste
    If InCopy > 0 And InCopy < 10 Then GoTo GoInCopy
    If InPaste > 0 And InPaste < 10 Then GoTo GoInPaste
    Resume Next
```

It will trigger the error on `ViewerWS.Paste`.

It prints this on the console:

> Error caught : Method 'Paste' of object '_Worksheet' failed / 0 / 1

I wrote the whole error handler to keep trying but it won't.

You hit debug then F5 and it works every time.

Comment: I've seen this before - see the function `PasteWithRetry` here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74632033/478884

Comment: Thanks, that looks very similar to my problem. I'll try this syntax next time when I'm at work and report if it worked here.