# Non-fatal error pasting image of Excel range to email

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I get an error in Set img = outlookMail.GetInspector.WordEditor.Range.Paste`.

The code is working because I get an Outlook email to send an image that I got in Excel.

Why am I getting an error?

> error 424 object required

```vb
Sub CreateOutlookEmailWithImage()

Dim outlookApp As Outlook.Application
Dim outlookMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim img As Object

Set outlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set outlookMail = outlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

' Get the active worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet

' Copy the image of the data from columns A to V
ws.Range("A1:V" & ws.Range("A1000000").End(xlUp).Row).CopyPicture

' Create a new email in Outlook
With outlookMail
    .Subject = "IC Diff " & Range("A2") & " " & Month(Now) & "/" & Right(Year(Now), 2)
    .body = ""
    .Display
End With

' Paste the image into the email
Set img = outlookMail.GetInspector.WordEditor.Range.Paste

img.Width = Application.InchesToPoints(100)
img.Height = Application.InchesToPoints(50)

End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe use the code that Run de Bruin posts on his site?  [Mail range as picture in the body of Outlook mail](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail0.htm)

Comment: Is the image the correct size ?

Comment: If there is no solution you could try repeatedly pasting until there is no error. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75394839 leads to the idea for possible workaround PasteWithRetry https://stackoverflow.com/a/74632033/1571407